# Disable md-input-container validation Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I'm  creating a form using Angular 2. When I add the attribute `required` to my `<input>` I got this: [image: Ugly af]

What I want is just the second red margin, the one of the `input` tag, instead of the first margin that belongs to the `md-input-container`.

Is there a way to disable one of those margins?

html code:

```
<h2 class="mmm">Create building</h2>
<form #buildingForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(buildingForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <md-input-container>
      <input type="text" #nameRef mdInput required placeholder="Building name" name="name" ngModel>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" md-raised-button color="accent" class="pull-right">{{title}}</button>
</form>
```

css:

```
md-input-container input {
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

As you can see, my css only adapts the container size.

Answer (score 0):

css class that works:

```
.ng-invalid:not(form).mat-input-element  {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

original hint:

```
.mat-input-element{
  background-color: skyblue; /* replace with your color value */
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/KCuvFH2iE4J70dWCyS6S?p=preview)

Comment: Actually, that give me a hint. I will let you know if that works. I think that this is like half the solution though.

Comment: I was further looking into it, wasn't aware of the css that creates the left red border. I was able to do this way too https://plnkr.co/edit/KCuvFH2iE4J70dWCyS6S?p=preview

Comment: I like that. It uses angular elements inside the css.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nehal for the hint.

I think I just found a solution. Not a fancy one though.

When using `md-input-container` with an `<input mdInput required>` there are two classes that draw the invalid indicator. Those are `.mat-input-container` and `.mat-input-element`. As you can guess, removing the invalid indicator of one of them is simply as adding

```
.(mat-input-container or mat-input-element) {
    border-left: none;
}
```

This allow us to even change the color of these validations. I hope this will be useful for someone that have the same problem.

If anyone have a different solution it will be awesome, personally, I don't like CSS tricks.